# SICP terminology: computational object

Tags: scheme, lisp, terminology, sicp

What is the precise definition of a computational object in SICP?
Is it a value ? Is it an expression ? Its not quite clear to me, could you please tell me which is the correct meaning and explain why?

Could you please give examples in your explanation ?

I was trying to make sense of the terminology used in SICP by drawing a concept map (see below), but I got stuck with the meaning of computational object because I cannot decide whether the term refers to a value or to an expression?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Updated Concept Map after reading the answers:

[image]

Comment: +1 This is a somewhat conceptual question, and not necessary a specific programming question, but it's got merit, you've cited the source well, explained the question, and it's an important issue that many programmers overlook or gloss over early on.

Comment: a "computational object" is just some thing that can actually be placed in computer memory and manipulated by a computer program. a "variable" is an abstract concept expressing our ability to "name" a thing, so that a "variable"'s "value" is that thing.

Comment: Thank you Will for the helpful comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the key in the in text that you've underlined:

> A critical aspect of a programming language is the means it provides
>   for using names to refer to computational objects.  We say that the
>   name identifies a *variable* whose *value* is the object.

A "computational object" is anything that can be the value of variable.  Calling it a "computational object" as oppposed to simply an "object" probably just adds a bit of confusion here, since it's probably clear from context that *non*-computational objects (e.g., a piece of paper) can't be the value of a variable in a program. There are some things related to programs that aren't computational objects, either, though.

For instance, in Scheme, a variable isn't a computational object;  you can't store a variable in another variable.  In some languages, variables, or pointers, at least, *are* computational objects, and *can* be the value of a variable.

In the definitions in the text, we see source code (i.e., expressions).  Evaluating expressions produces computational values that can be stored in variables. For instance, the expression `(+ 2 3)` can be evaluated to produce the integer two, which gets printed as `2`.  It's interesting to note, though, that in the Lisp languages (and more generally, in homoiconic languages), that source code can also be represented as a value.  For instance, evaluating the expression `(list '+ 2 3)` produces a list of the symbol named `"+"`, the integer value two, and the integer value three.  The list is printed as `(+ 2 3)`.

So, we've got an idea of where objects are used, but what objects actually exist out there?  This depends on the definition of the language.  The definition of Scheme specifies some types of objects:

- numbers (and there are various types of numbers)
- symbols
- strings
- cons cells (these are essentially pairs, and we build lists and trees from them using conventions)
- the empty list
- boolean values true and false
- procedures (often called functions)
- vectors & arrays
- …

Other languages will provide other types, and Scheme may provide more than what I've listed here.  The point is that what objects exist is something decided by the language designers, and the intent is to give enough primitive types so that a programmer can define whatever they need in terms of them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now remains the question what is the definition of an object ? Anything that can be stored in a variable?

Comment: Also, what is a value of a variable? Is a variable an expression? The definition seems to be circular.

Comment: The value of a variable is an object;  it is neither a variable nor an expression.  I've added some discussion of what objects actually are.

Comment: So the term "value" is overloaded? The value of a variable is not the same concept as a value of an expression?

Comment: It's not overloaded.  The value of a variable is an object, but not every object has to be the value of a variable.  If you do `(define x (cons 1 (cons 2 '())))`, there's only one variable, `x`, and its value is a cons cell.  There are five distinct values though: two cons cells, two numbers, and the empty list.

Comment: So two different expressions can correspond to the same computational object ? Like `(+ 2 2)` and `(* 2 2)`?

Comment: Evaluating different expressions can indeed result in the same object.  Indeed, that's very important.  If you do `(define x ...)` and `(define y (list x ...))`, you should very much hope that evaluating `x` and `(car y)` will produce the same value! Or, as you mentioned,  `(+ 2 2)` and `(* 2 2)` should definitely produce the same result!  That said, sometimes "same" can be overloaded.  We can have two different lists that have the same elements.  E.g., evaluating `(list 1 2)` multiple times produces different objects, but clearly *as lists* they're equivalent in a sense.  That's why Scheme...

Comment: ...has multiple equality predicates, including `eq?`, `equal?`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Now I can continue with SICP !

Answer (score 2):

I think the term "computational" is just there to differentiate these objects from physical objects.  In your concept map, it might be "the same as value".  Note that almost anything can be an object and be manipulated in Scheme, including expressions (in macros/metaprogramming).

Comment: Is a variable an expression?

Comment: Is an orange a house?

Comment: But what did you mean by asking this rhetorical question?